# $\pi$ does not lie in any quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, irrational-numbers

Knowing that $\pi^2$ is irrational:

How can we prove that
$\pi$ does not lie in any quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Without using that $\pi$ is transcendent.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all we know about $\pi$ is that $\pi^2$ is irrational, then we can't conclude that $\pi$ isn't quadratic over $\Bbb{Q}$. After all, $(\sqrt{2}+1)^2$ is irrational, but $\sqrt{2}+1$ generates a quadratic extension.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

** Any *finite* extension of a field is an algebraic extension of that field

** Any element of an algebraic extension of a field is algebraic over that field

** Any element of an extension of a field of degree $\,n\,$ is a root of a non-zero polynomial over that field of degree at least $\,n\,$

Comment: These hints don't seem to be leading towards an answer.

Comment: The comment forced me to read more carefully: I missed that "without using that $\,\pi\,$ is trascendental" part in the OP...Anyway I leave the answer here in case someone can do without that part.